# In GCP , I can able to view GKE Monitoring dashboard. How to create alerts for CPU and memory Utilization for Kubernetes Container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

I have enabled Default GCP Monitoring in my Google Kubernetes Cluster. So GKE Dashboard is created which contains System Metrics. Now I need to enable alert for Kubernetes container's CPU and memory Utilization from GKE dashboard. I tried to create own alert, but it didn't match with metrics defined in GKE dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Guide1](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/observing) and [Guide2](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/observing)  for monitoring the Kubernetes engine. In it, you can know about alerting and how to monitor your system. In case you were already familiar, [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/migration#resource_type_changes) is a list of the metrics for the new Kubernetes engine in comparison to the previous metrics. Additionally, the complete list of metrics, which are always useful, can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_k8s_container).

In Monitoring dashboard, dashboard displays [CPU and Memory utilization](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/observing?_ga=2.128661900.-1633620421.1612797851#tables)  in time range:

**CPU utilization**: The CPU utilization of containers that can be attributed to a resource within the selected time span. The metric used is [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes#kubernetes) check with For CPU Utilization

**Memory utilization**: The memory utilization of containers that can be attributed to a resource within the selected time span. The metric used is [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes#kubernetes) check with For Memory Utilization

The command "kubectl top node" displays resource (CPU/Memory/Storage) [usage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) at that moment, not time span.